# Test symfony doctrine UnitOfWork error only during tests

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpunit

I have a problem during testing a symfony App with phpunit.
I created a service and it works well but when I execute the service in my tests doctrine throw me an exception

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'PointOfSale#country' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity
```

In my service I do this:

```
$pointOfSale->setCountry($this->getCountry($name));

private function getCountry(string $name): Country
    {
        $country = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Country::class)->findOneBy(['alpha3Code' => $name]);
        return $country;
    }
```

I don't understand why this entity is not managed by UnitOfWorks. Indeed when I do the following code I have an exception only during test

```
$country = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Country::class)->findOneBy(['alpha3Code' => $name]);
$this->entityManager->refresh($country);
```

```
 [ERROR] Entity Namespace\Country@000000001bfea0ed00000000602457d6 is not managed. An entity is    
         managed if its fetched from the database or registered as new through EntityManager#persist
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Your code looks right. Do you call $this->entityManager->clear(); anywhere in your code? That will make the entity manager forget all found entities.

Comment: To confirm my error I did a refresh just after findOneBy and got error. So no clear

Comment: You fetch the country with $this->entityManager but refresh it with $this->coreManager. It looks like coreManager is not aware of the unitOfWork of entityManager. Why are you using two managers?

Comment: It's the same manage (bad rename for example). After `findOneBy` if I do `$this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->isInIdentityMap($country)` it returns true but it returns false in tests

Answer (score 0):

Solution was discuss here:

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/1112#event-3005473120

[doctrine changelog note] (https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/1.12.x/UPGRADE-1.12.md#unitofwork-cleared-between-each-request)

Answer (score 0):

While troubleshooting the same problem with PhpUnit Testing producing "A new entity was found through the relationship" errors I realized I was actually getting different Entity Manager instances thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361816/why-does-autowiring-provides-a-different-entity-manager-instance-for-event-subsc). What I did was move the `self::bootKernel()` from my `__construct` function to a new "startUp" function that I run at beginning of each test function and then I started getting the correct Entity Manager each time instead of a different one each test.

I may be missing something, but now my tests pass and produce the same results as my actual program.